# Error com.opennetcf.extensions.pcl is not compatible with netstandard1.5

Tags: xamarin.forms, pcl

I'm trying to understand the root of this error:

Package com.opennetcf.extensions.pcl is not compatible with netstandard1.5

I get it when I try to update xamarin essentials from nuget in my xamarin forms project. If I don't update that package, the project works fine. This is what I don't understand. If the PCL is not compatilble with .net standard 1.5, why does the project currently work when I'm using both. Why do I only see this error when I try to update xamarin essentials?

I've been reading a lot of articles on PCL support but I'm not sure what I need to do in this case. My main concern is updating xamarin essentials.

Any thoughts?

Comment: that package hasn't been updated in 4 years, and PCL has been deprecated.  What version of Essentials are you currently on?

Comment: 1.1.0. I can't remove the package because too much legacy code depends on it.

Comment: that version of Essentials is 2+ years old - I'd guess at some point they removed PCL support and that is what's causing the problem